# match php variable 'foobar' to 'Foo Bar' in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, regex

my mysql table contains an entry

```
Foo Bar
```

*(i.e will potentially include capitals and whitespace)*

I need search the DB using the string 'foobar' and match this

*foobar is generated originally from the DB using:*

```
$i = str_replace(' ','',$i);
$i = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", "", $i);
$i = strtolower($i);
```

Comment: If you won't have any delimiter between words you'll get in a big trouble. I think, you have to change logic, how 'foobar' is generated.

Comment: I've toyed with the idea of getting ALL the DB data, converting the field using the str_replace... method and matching it to 'foobar' whist also extracting the row ID - I would then fetch 'Foo Bar' matching the row ID. This would in principal work, but seems messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only spaces are the problem, and your collation is case-insensitive:

```
WHERE REPLACE(tn.fieldname,' ','') LIKE 'foobar';
```

if your collation is case-sensitive:

```
WHERE LOWER(REPLACE(tn.fieldname,' ','')) LIKE LOWER('foobar');
```

It will however result in a full-table scan, so not a great performance. Normalizing `fieldname` to what you are searching for, or another column with a normalized `fieldname` would perform better, especially with an index on it.

Comment: The OP said "*special characters*" too.

Comment: .. in which case the second portion of the answer goes into effect.

Comment: I like this - does exactly what I need. I've used: I stupidly included the need for special characters (now removed from my question) which I don't need as the string makes up part of my URL. Many thanks

Comment: I've used:

WHERE LOWER(REPLACE(tn.fieldname,' ','')) = 'foobar' - unsure why I would need LOWER('foobar')?

Comment: No need, if you _know_ it's going to be lowercase. Also, remember: `select _utf8'a' COLLATE 'utf8_bin' =  _utf8'A' COLLATE 'utf8_bin';` is false, but `select _utf8'a' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci' =  _utf8'A' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci';` is true, so depending on the collation you don't even need the first one.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't easy to convert `Foo Bar` to `foobar` in MySQL prior to performing comparisons (although [it is possible with UDFs](http://www.mysqludf.org/lib_mysqludf_preg/)).  Then you need only do:

```
WHERE LOWER(preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', '', field)) = 'foobar'
```

The easiest option would be to use [regular expression pattern matching](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html), which isn't case sensitive by default—simply insert `[^[:alnum:]]*` between every character in `foobar` (within PHP) and then search the database:

```
WHERE field RLIKE '^[^[:alnum:]]*f[^[:alnum:]]*o[^[:alnum:]]*o[^[:alnum:]]*b[^[:alnum:]]*a[^[:alnum:]]*r[^[:alnum:]]*$'
```

I think the most elegant (though somewhat harder) solution would be to [define your own collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/adding-collation.html) that ignores non alphanumeric characters and lettercase and then use that.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply and links. UDF is a bit beyond my ability and I don't need the ability for spec chars after all.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't have anything equivalent to gawk's `gensub()` or PHP's `preg_replace()`.  While you could use MySQL's [**`REPLACE()`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) and [**`LOWER()`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_lower) functions to remove specific characters, you can't tell MySQL to remove `/[^[:alnum:]]/`.

My suggestion would be to use a [UDF](https://launchpad.net/mysql-udf-regexp).